# ExoPlayer: how to change color of controller's elements

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a custom control introduced via `exo_player_control_view.xml` file. The only difference I need is a different color of the elements (buttons and timeline).

But it turns out I'd need to copy-paste all icons' xmls changing only color attribute. It is of course doable but I hope there is a simper way.

Another problem is that the icons are under Apache 2.0 license ([example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/ExoPlayer/f7ed789fc3841b2536f5629c6bb10f4cb4ee5130/library/ui/src/main/res/drawable-anydpi-v21/exo_icon_rewind.xml)) and I'm not sure whether it is allowed to copy them to my project.

**Question:** How to change color of controller's elements? Is it possible to do it without copying and modifying standard icons?

Comment: Did you already check this one
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a?

Comment: Yes, I did, but no luck in solving my problem

Answer (score 3):

Actually doing something similar here using tinting.  Assuming your exoplayer layout xml file contains following

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
    val playButton = audioView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_play)
    tintButton(playButton, color)
    val pauseButton = audioView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_pause)
    tintButton(pauseButton, color)
    val prevButton = audioView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_prev)
    tintButton(prevButton, color)
    val rewindButton = audioView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_rew)
    tintButton(rewindButton, color)
    val ffwdButton = audioView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_ffwd)
    tintButton(ffwdButton, color)
```

and

```
private fun tintButton(button: ImageButton, color: Int) {
    val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(button.drawable)
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(), ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
    button.setImageDrawable(drawable)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got the idea. May be I'm messing something out, but it doesn't work like this. I'm invoking the code from `onStart()` method of my fragment and my fragment is a part of `ViewPager` each fragment of which contains such controller. I'm currently trying to figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageButton play = findViewById(R.id.exo_play);
Drawable drawable = play.getDrawable();
drawable.setTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#41a8ff")));
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). I will try this out once I have a chance.